# Получить все значения параметра GET-запроса

Tags: php

Язык php. Вызывается скрипт, которому передается следующая строка get-параметров: `post=5&related=thread&related=forum&related=user`.

Как получать одиночные параметры из нее мне понятно (`$_GET['post']`). А как получить из нее все значения параметра `related`, т.е. `thread`, `forum` и `user`?

Comment: Проблема в том, что от меня не зависит, что придет на сервер. В качестве примера присылаемой строки мне дана `post=5&related=thread&related=forum&related=user`. И вот мне надо с ней как-то работать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь, все что передается в запросе - это отдельные переменные, а не массив

Если хотите это как-то сгруппировать, то у вас должно быть что-то типа такого `post=5&related=thread,forum,user`.

А на сервере применить `explode` для отделения этих данных

В ином случае на стороне сервера, вы просто не сможете извлечь все данные из массива `$_GET`. Так как в него попадет только одно последнее значение `related`, в приведенном примере это будет `user`

Единственный способ достать на сервере эту строку будет использование массива `$_SERVER`, а конкретно `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

В таком случае надо будет написать свою функцию парсинга данной строки.

Answer (score 5):

Получить ваши переменные как элементы массива можно вот так:

```
<?php
$query  = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

foreach($query as $param)
{
    list($name, $value) = explode('=', $param, 2);
    echo $value;
}
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, практически так я это и реализовал.

Answer (score 1):

Пробуйте так:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: Оно выводит post-параметры и позволяет получить чистые post-параметры без привязки к названиям.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы можете повлиять на саму GET-строку, то передавайте `related` в виде массива, а именно:

```
http://example.com?post=5&related[]=thread&related[]=forum&related[]=user
```

Тогда у Вас `$_GET['related']` тоже будет представлен в виде массива, иначе он просто берёт последнее значение `related`, т.к. считает его строковым параметром